# What is the default location for RAW data on my phone

Tags: android

Good morning Stack,

I am new on Android development and I am developing an application for my phone.
I have files that I added to the raw folder in my eclipse folder.
I am wondering where are stored the files from my raw folder in my phone and what would be the path to access them.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know you can't access them in absolute-path way.
For example you could use this:

```
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);